# regex int + comma

Tags: php, regex, pcre

i need a regex for: `123,456,789,123,4444,..`. basically comma separated values. The INT part can be 1-4 numbers long, followed by a comma...always in this form...

```
/^([0-9]{1,4})(\,)?$/
```

This obviously doesn't work...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/^[0-9]{1,4}(?:,[0-9]{1,4})*$/
```

This will match any comma separated sequence of one or more digit sequences with one to four digits. `(?:…)` is a so called non-capturing group that’s match cannot be referenced separately like you can with “normal” capturing groups `(…)`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
/^\d{1,4}(?:,\d{1,4})*+$/D
```

This will match any comma-separated sequence of one or more digit sequences with one to four digits. The `D` modifier makes sure that any trailing newline character does not mistakenly result in a positive match.

Comment: Please make it less obvious that you copied my answer.

Comment: What's with the `*+`? Is that a typo, or a construct that I'm unaware of?

Comment: @Gumbo, no. Why *hide* that I copied your answer?

Comment: @Ryan Kinal, it's a [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html).